# Connection refused with Bitcoin Armory daemon

Tags: python, bitcoin

For one of our products, we want to use armory as “watch-only” online wallet with the armoryd daemon, so that we can access it via JSON-RPC calls from a client. I have started bitcoind and armoryd, I have all necessary steps done with offline wallet file, etc, but I have a problem. I cannot access armoryd, I can’t find the credentials which I should use in order to connect. The result is that all my RPC calls get a “`Connection refused`” as a response.

Below is the configuration I’m trying to use:

```
python armoryd.py --debug --rpcport=7070 --skip-version-check --skip-online-check <walletFile.wallet>
```

I have added `/user/.armory/armoryd.conf` with `user:abc123` for credentials but I’m not sure if it’s only this. Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, armoryd will relay RPC commands to the bitcoin core running on your computer using the specified --rpcport or the default one(if you don't specified any rpcport). If armory manage your bitcoin core it's transparent for you and you won't see the link with the bitcoin core.

What appends: armoryd is calling the bitcoin core on port 7070 and nobody answers which causes: " Connection refused ".

Two solutions: go to your bitcoin code main folder and edit the file "bitcoin.conf" and edit/add "-rpcport=7070" or use the bitcoin core default rpcport which should be 18333 for the testnet.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think armoryd is honoring your port selection, and the other arguments I'm not sure about, I just had some success using the default port as described here:

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=494956.msg5452723#msg5452723